# JavaFX - Set Slider value after dragging mouse button

Tags: user-interface, javafx, slider

I'm writing music player and I don't know how to code slider dragging handler to set value after user frees mouse button. When I write simple MouseDragged method dragging brings non estetic "rewinding" sound because mediaplayer changes value every time slider moves. While playing slider automatic changes value by mediaplayer listener to synchronize with track duration. This is what I got so far.

```
ChangeListener<Duration> timeListener =  new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(
            ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observableValue,
            Duration duration,
            Duration current) {
        durSlider
                .setValue(current
                        .toSeconds());
    }
};

durSlider.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

                    mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(durSlider.getValue()));

                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 13):

The [`valueChanging` property of the slider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#valueChangingProperty) indicates if the slider is in the process of being changed. It is an observable property, so you can attach a listener directly to it, and respond when the value stops changing:

```
durSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, Boolean wasChanging, Boolean isNowChanging) {
        if (! isNowChanging) {
            mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(durSlider.getValue()));
        }
    }
});
```

This won't change the position of the player if the user clicks on the "track" on the slider, or uses the keyboard to move it. For that, you can register a listener with the value property. You need to be careful here, because the value is also going to change via your time listener. In theory, the time listener should set the value of the slider, and then that should cause an attempt to set the current time of the player to the exact value it already has (which would result in a no-op). However, rounding errors will likely result in a lot of small adjustments, causing the "static" you are observing. To fix this, only move the media player if the change is more than some small minimum amount:

```
private static double MIN_CHANGE = 0.5 ; //seconds

// ...

durSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> obs, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        if (! durSlider.isValueChanging()) {
            double currentTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toSeconds();
            double sliderTime = newValue.doubleValue();
            if (Math.abs(currentTime - sliderTime) > 0.5) {
                mediaPlayer.seek(newValue.doubleValue());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, you don't want your time listener to move the slider if the user is trying to drag it:

```
ChangeListener<Duration> timeListener =  new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(
            ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observableValue,
            Duration duration,
            Duration current) {
        if (! durSlider.isValueChanging()) {
            durSlider.setValue(current.toSeconds());
        }
    }
};
```

Here's a complete example (using lambdas for brevity):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class VideoPlayerTest extends Application {

    private static final String MEDIA_URL =
            "http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv";

    private static final double MIN_CHANGE = 0.5 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(MEDIA_URL));
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

        Slider slider = new Slider();
        player.totalDurationProperty().addListener((obs, oldDuration, newDuration) -> slider.setMax(newDuration.toSeconds()));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(mediaView, null, null, slider, null);

        slider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((obs, wasChanging, isChanging) -> {
            if (! isChanging) {
                player.seek(Duration.seconds(slider.getValue()));
            }
        });

        slider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (! slider.isValueChanging()) {
                double currentTime = player.getCurrentTime().toSeconds();
                if (Math.abs(currentTime - newValue.doubleValue()) > MIN_CHANGE) {
                    player.seek(Duration.seconds(newValue.doubleValue()));
                }
            }
        });

        player.currentTimeProperty().addListener((obs, oldTime, newTime) -> {
            if (! slider.isValueChanging()) {
                slider.setValue(newTime.toSeconds());
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 540, 280);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        player.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you apparently didin't notice my timeListener property. Your solution works only without putting it on but then slider doesn't synchronize with track duration. When I put your listeners with it, whole playing process goes wrong because value of slider is chaning every passed second, not only when user clicks on it.

Comment: Ah, I thought it would work anyway, because it should just seek to the same position it's already at. I guess there is some rounding somewhere which is causing it to repeatedly make very small adjustments. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works fine. Looked like dead end to me but your idea with static double variable was brilliant

Comment: I had nearly the same code already but was wondering on how to get key adjustments working? Still doesn't work with your version...