# How to make Slider moves automatically

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I do need to know how to make my Slider JavaFX control automatically moves (without mouse). My idea is: have a voice recorder system and the Slider moves every second, equal to the Media Player. Someone please help me ???

Reguards!

Comment: What prevents you from calling `Slider.setValue()` in a Task/Timeline?

Comment: Is there already any specific code we can talk about?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552495/javafx-set-slider-value-after-dragging-mouse-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sliderObj.setValue();

```
    int nValue = m_objSlider.getValue();
    int nMaxValue = m_objSlider.getMaximum();
    nValue = nValue + 5;
    m_objSlider.setValue(nValue);
```

5 = is the value that you can set depends on your frame.