# JavaFX - Where is Slider behaviour implemented and how to utilise it?

Tags: java, javafx, slider, javafx-8, media-player

I have a Slider that is updated in my code every few milliseconds, because it displays the current progress of a MediaPlayer, but when the user adjusts the Slider, it should seek.

### Current implementation

```
MutableBoolean seeking = new MutableBoolean();
seekSlider.setOnMousePressed(e -> seeking.setTrue());
seekSlider.setOnMouseReleased(e -> { 
    player.seek(Duration.millis(seekSlider.getValue())); 
    Platform.runLater(() -> seeking.setFalse());
});

player.addPlaybackTimeListener(time -> {
    if(seeking.isFalse())
        seekSlider.setValue(time.toMillis());
});
```

But this is not ideal, since it only works for mouse controls and not when the slider is adjusted with the Keyboard(left and right arrow). And when trying to add this, it completely fails, because the key adjustments are simply overridden:

```
seekSlider.setOnKeyPressed(e -> player.seek(Duration.millis(seekSlider.getValue())));
```

### Question

Now i wonder if there is a way to generally detect when the user changes the value of a Slider. While looking into the Slider class I realised that there is absolutely NO logic in there, only Properties. That leads to two questions:

1. Where is all the Slider logic?
2. Can I bind to it in a way that allows continuous updating while the user is still able to make any manual adjustments?

I also found this question: [JavaFX - Set Slider value after dragging mouse button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552495/javafx-set-slider-value-after-dragging-mouse-button) but it also did not work for Key changes.

Comment: Take a look at the skin (returned from `createDefaultSkin`). The logic should be there.

Comment: yeah I found that, but can I access it somehow?

Comment: please provide a MCVE that demonstrates the problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)